# Possible bug in opencv matrix reduction of gpumat

Tags: c++, opencv

```
reduce(const GpuMat& mtx, GpuMat& vec, int dim, int reduceOp, int dtype=-1, Stream& stream=Stream::Null())
```

It seems that the third parameter dim doesn't work at all. No matter dim = 0 or dim = 1, it only reduces the input gpumat to a single row. I tried both opencv 2.4.6 and 3.0.0. Both of them have the same issue.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This may be more suitable to the opencv site. Did you search the [issues](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/issues)?

Comment: I did search the opencv site but didn't find it. Probably I should post a bug report there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. The `cv::gpu::reduce` function reduces the matrix to a vector, and the vector is represented as a single row matrix. If `dim == 0` `dst` will have `[1 x src.cols]` size, if `dim == 1` `dst` will have `[1 x src.rows]` size.

Comment: This explains everything! Thanks!